# No matches on string comparison (with regex filter) & notify only on new values

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, compare

I am developing an app that checks a classified ad website for the newest ads. It should notify me when there is a new ad at a special price.

`i` is the price value i'm ready to pay and `m1` are all prices on from the website, additionally, it shows the results in a `textbox`.
For some reason, the comparison doesn't work. Eventually, I want to alter further so that it only notifies me of new values.

To clarify what i mean: the price of the product is as a string, the only way i know to find a cheap price is to compare two strings: one of the original price and one of what i'm ready to pay.

I hope its now clear what i mean :)

**On Button-Click**:

```
{
    int i =0;
    List<string> codes = new List<string>();
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    String html = web.DownloadString("http://www.dhd24.com/azl/index.php?sortorder=51&zeilen_pro_seite=60&suchstring=graupapagei&plz=&umkreis=20&classid=0&nav=classtypeid%3AMQ%3B");
    MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"(.....,-)", 
        RegexOptions.Singleline);               

    while (i < 700) {
        foreach (Match m in m1) {
            i++;
            string test = (i.ToString() + ",-");
            string d = test.Replace("  ", string.Empty);
            string f = m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("  ", string.Empty); ;

            if (d == f)
                MessageBox.Show("found one!");

            string code = m.Groups[1].Value;
            codes.Add(code);
        }                           
    }      

    listBox1.DataSource = codes;  
}
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverFlow! It's not clear from your post what comparison is not working for you. Is it the new price compared to the old price? Also No need to respond to this comment - just edit your post so that we can understand your question a bit better.

Comment: Your Regex seems to be incorrect. If you want to select decimal numbers, use `/d+(./d{2,3})?`. And the whole method sounds a little bit wrong. `0100.00` is not equal to `100`. I would prefer to write a method that passes on the digits and calculates value, not that hard on a simple number format.

Comment: I tried it with '/d+(./d{2,3})?', but with this method my textbox just shows many empty lines. I don't know waht im doing wrong :/